# Ajax call in react js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Hi I am new to `react js`.I am trying to make a ajax call in `react js` to get data
This is my code for ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/menu-item',
    data: checkBox
})
.done(function (data) {
    alert(data);
})
.fail(function (data) {
    console.log('failed to register');
});
```

Here I am getting an error as:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/menu-item 404 (Not Found)
```

I don't know which method I have to pass the`url`.
This my `.js` file

```
var express = require('express');
//express.use(require('connect').bodyParser());
var router = express();
var path = require('path');
var Menu = require('../models/menu');
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var db = require('../db');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    router.post('/menu-item', function(req, res) {

console.log("------request-------"+req);

  var formDetails = {

    checkBox: req.body.checkBox
  };

  var newFormDetails = new Menu({
    checkBox: formDetails.checkBox

  });
  newFormDetails.save(function(saveErr, formId) {
    if (saveErr){
      res.notFound();
    } else {
      res.send(newFormDetails);
      console.log("Saved successfully"+newFormDetails);
    };
  });
});

return router;

}
```

Please any suggestion..

Comment: Since `http://localhost:3000/menu-item` is wrong, what is the correct url you need for your ajax call?

Comment: That's what I am trying to get. My react component is `MenuItem`. I have given url for that as `/menu-item`. But I am getting `page not found` for that url

Comment: Are you trying to import a react component with Ajax?!

Comment: Make sure that you are passing a correct `url`

Comment: `if (saveErr){res.notFound();` wat... save errors shouldn't becoem 404 errors...

Answer (score -1):

Could your problem be due to this line of code:

```
if (saveErr){
  res.notFound();
} else {
```

Essentially, that line is saying that if you have an error saving to mongo, don't throw an exception or return the error but return a 404.  That could mean your error isn't with routing but with mongo instead. 
 That would be my first place to debug. Would be worth console logging saveErr.

Comment: Why did this get down voted? You _were_ hitting the correct url, so I'm guessing your save was failing and throwing the 404.